# TypeError: residuals_all_exp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'datasets_dict'

Tags: python, function, parameters

I created a function

```
def residuals_all_exp(t_grid_online, p, y0_dict, c_dict, datasets_dict):
```

When I call the function in another script with

```
result = minimize(residuals_all_exp, p, args=(y0_dict, c_dict, datasets_dict), method='leastsq', nan_policy= "omit")
```

the error

> TypeError: residuals_all_exp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'datasets_dict'

occures. Why? Is it because I defined the function with

```
t_grid_online, p, y0_dict, c_dict, datasets_dict
```

but only gave

```
 p, args=(y0_dict, c_dict, datasets_dict)
```

?

Thus, is python not actually reading the parameters inside the parantehse of the function definition?

Comment: most likely, have you tested it without args=(...)?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to minimize a function f, you should have minimize(f, x0, args=()). with x0 being the value where the algorithm will first evaluate your function.

Comment: The minimizer is from lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html). I was able to solve by just adding

t_grid_online

to the minimizer